# Esconder Div no IOS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, aplicação-web

Possuo um botão de redirecionamento para o whatsapp no meu site que não funciona no ios, teria alguma forma de esconde-lo só para esse OS? No caso ele está dentro de um href no html, bastaria esconde-la quando o usuário estiver usando IOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar uma abordagem deste tipo,

```
var ehIOS = /iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(navigator.userAgent) && !window.MSStream;

if(ehIOS){
   //codigo para ocultar
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! funcionou!